# Что не так со строкой?

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [
"data"=>'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
"options"=>'option_id=' + option_id + '&option_value=' + option_value
];
```

Ошибка - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Только просьба по делу...

Comment: Вы, кажется, с PHP пересели на JS, да?

Comment: Да, но ведь вроде бы правильно.. =) Или все же нет?=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JS объект делается как-то так:

```
var data = {
data:"product_id=" + product_id + "&quantity=" + quantity,
options:"option_id=" + option_id + "&option_value=" + option_value
};
```